# How to split up a list of lists Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists

```
myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
```

and I want to split it up into three separate list, each with their own name:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9,10]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 3):

You could unpack it directly:

```
a, b, c = myList
```

Answer (score 0):

python is easy, you can do

```
a,b,c=mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

To create new variables, you can use `globals()`:

```
import string
myList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
for i, value in enumerate(myList):
   globals()[string.ascii_lowercase[i]] = value

print(a, b, c)
```

Output:

```
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Comment: I was thinking we don't need a 3rd answer on this, but then I learned something! :)

Comment: Not going to comment on the use of `globals()` :)  Any reason not to just `for name, value in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, myList):`?