# How to convert a two dimensional list into a list of each row

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, python-3.7

```
A=[[1,3,5,7],[2,5,8,12,16],[4,7,8,12]]
```

I would like the result to be

```
[1,3,5,7][2,5,8,12,16][4,7,8,12]
```

Comment: what type of data-structure is your desired result?

Comment: [1,3,5,7][2,5,8,12,16][4,7,8,12]

Comment: You can't put lists next to each other like that. Do you want a string of your lists? `"[1,3,5,7][2,5,8,12,16][4,7,8,12]"`?

Comment: Yes as Nick said, you should be getting either string of lists, or list of lists or so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split up a list of lists Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584845/how-to-split-up-a-list-of-lists-python)

Answer (score 0):

you can unpack your list A like this:

```
A = [[1,3,5,7],[2,5,8,12,16],[4,7,8,12]]

list1, list2, list3 = A

print(list1, list2, list3)
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7] [2, 5, 8, 12, 16] [4, 7, 8, 12]
```

in this case, you have to be sure that A has always 3 lists inside

Comment: So what if its more than 3 list ?

Comment: This works but how do you use it in list comprehension